# Android Webview is slow

Tags: android, performance, android-webview

I tried to add http://208.77.22.13/proprek_android/property-listing-trends.php?PropertyID=63&placeId=1&property_type=1&BuildingName=Arabian%20Ranches%20&BedRooms=4

in webview but its loading speed is very slow.I tried in desktop browser its loading is very fast.

```
wv1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewdetail);
    WebSettings webSettings = wv1.getSettings();
    webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        // chromium, enable hardware acceleration
        wv1.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    } else {
        // older android version, disable hardware acceleration
        wv1.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
```

i added this code to android but stil slow why?

Comment: i have added a full code that is more fresh and working. You can take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **1.build.gradle(Project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2'}
    } // this is the single line you are adding to project level gradle file.else is generated.
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

2. > **build.gradle(app)**

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   android {
       compileSdkVersion 25 //put your desired version
       buildToolsVersion "25.0.0" // put your desired version
       defaultConfig {
           applicationId "com.example.arsensench.xwalk" //put your package name
           minSdkVersion 16 // min sdk should be 16
           targetSdkVersion 25 // target sdk can be your desierd
           versionCode 1
           versionName "1.0"
           testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
       }
       buildTypes {
           release {
               minifyEnabled false
               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
           }
       }
   }

   dependencies {
       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
           exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
       })
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
       testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
      //until here everything is generated
      //the line below is using the latest XWALK.
   compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:22.52.561.4'
   ```

   }

> **3. AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.arsensench.xwalk"><!-- your package name-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

> **4.MainActivity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.arsensench.xwalk.MainActivity"> <!--your class path-->

    <org.xwalk.core.XWalkView
        android:id="@+id/xwalkWebView"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

> **5.MainActivity.java()**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.xwalk.core.XWalkView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        XWalkView xWalkWebView=(XWalkView)findViewById(R.id.xwalkWebView);
        xWalkWebView.load("http://208.77.22.13/proprek_android/property-listing-trends.php?PropertyID=63&placeId=1&property_type=1&BuildingName=Arabian%20Ranches%20&BedRooms=4", null);
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment !

Comment: calm down @Piyush. Code had arrived.

Comment: your site is loading and scrolling very hard even on PC Google chrome. It has something to do with your site. For example http://www.theverge.com/ is working great with the code i provide you.

Answer (score 1):

I checked URL you gave in my browser and it takes almost 30 seconds to load, so there is nothing wrong with your code

Comment: true. this page is loading during runtime few dozen of seconds... maybe your desktop is connected via ethernet or have cached this site?